# Ubuntu on Macbook: How to restore default boot to Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, macbook

I have a Macbook pro (late 2015) with two partitions: one with Mac OS and the other one with an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS operating system. It was always booting to Ubuntu by default and I used the Alt-key on startup to boot into Mac OS when I needed to.

A few days ago there was a hardware issue on my macbook, so I brought it to the nearest Apple Store and they fixed the problem. After I received it back from the store, I noticed that it is now booting to Mac OS by default.

I checked the partitions to see, whether the Ubuntu system was removed by the store or if they wiped the HD but everything seems to be in place.

How can I restore the old behavior so my Macbook boots into Ubuntu by default again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're suffering from what I call a [boot coup.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) See that page for details, but you can try this:

1. Boot to Ubuntu. Given your current situation, you may need to use an Ubuntu installation disk in its "try before installing" mode or use my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R to boot into your regular Ubuntu on a one-time basis.
2. In a Terminal window, type `sudo efibootmgr -v`. This will show your current EFI boot options. My suspicion is that one of these will be called `ubuntu`, but that the `BootOrder` will show a macOS entry as being first. (If `efibootmgr` complains that it can't find EFI boot variables, then you've booted in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. Try again, but pick a different boot option for Ubuntu.)
3. At this point there are two possibilities:

   - If I'm right in my suspicion that you have an existing `ubuntu` entry, you can set it first by typing `sudo efibootmgr -o ####[,####,####,....]`, where the first `####` is the number of the `ubuntu` entry and subsequent numbers are the remaining entries in the current boot order. Alternatively, you could use the `refind-mkdefault` script described on my boot coup page, and that comes with rEFInd. You can download it directly [here.](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/code/ci/master/tree/refind-mkdefault?format=raw) Type `sudo ./refind-mkdefault --label ubuntu` to set the Ubuntu entry as first.
   - If `efibootmgr` does not show an `ubuntu` entry, then you need to create a new one. The command to do so is `sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi -L ubuntu`. You can omit `-d /dev/sda` if that's the hard disk where GRUB is installed and `-p 1` if your ESP is partition #1; and if your disk and/or partition are *not* those values, you must adjust the `efibootmgr` command appropriately. If you were using a UEFI-based PC, it would be safer to specify `shimx64.efi` rather than `grubx64.efi`. On a Mac, either should work; but on the off chance that `shimx64.efi` isn't installed, `grubx64.efi` will work and is more direct. As an alternative to this, you could run [Boot Repair.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) This is less intimidating if you're not comfortable with text-mode command-line tools, but Boot Repair is overkill and runs a small risk of making matters worse, so I prefer to stick with `efibootmgr` as a first attempt.

If neither of these approaches work, it could be that your Ubuntu was installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. In this case, there are several possibilities for how to recover it to boot in that mode again, depending on what's wrong; but it's likely to be easier to recover it to boot in EFI mode by using Boot Repair *in EFI mode* or by installing rEFInd from OS X. The latter will change how you boot, though; instead of holding down Alt to select your OS, the rEFInd menu will appear automatically on every boot and enable you to pick your OS.